# operator * cannot be applied to decimal and double c#

Tags: c#, tax

I am currently making a tax program (study project) that read in a CSV file and generates a list of people and account balances, i need to round down 2 decimal places from one text box and add them up in another text box. my code attached tell me i cannot use " * " how do i times a decimal with 0.1? and if i am doing this wrong let me know, cheers!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //CSV ARRAY LISTS
    List<string> fullName = new List<string>();
    List<string> accBalance = new List<string>();

    int currentItem;
    int index;
    int counter = 0;

    decimal interestBalance = 0;
    decimal result;

    decimal interestRemainder = 0;
    double round = 0.1;


 private void interestBalanceBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        interestRemainder = decimal.Parse(interestBalanceBox.Text);
        interestRemainder = Math.Truncate(0.1 * interestRemainder) / 100;
        interestRemainderBox.Text = interestRemainder.ToString();

    }
```

the program we are meant to represent is this one here! any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Decide whether you want to use `decimal` math or `double` math. `decimal * decimal => decimal` is well-defined, as is `double * double => double`. So when you've decided which you want to use: cast to the right type and use that. Anything involving finance is usually `decimal`. If the problem is simply the `0.1`, then: either multiply by `0.1M`, or just divide by `10`

Answer (score 9):

```
interestRemainder = Math.Truncate((decimal)0.1 * interestRemainder) / 100;
```

You need to cast the 0.1 to the same type as the other operand

Comment: aw aha thanks man works now :D ill remember that for next time! cheers!

Comment: `0.1M` is probably simpler than `(decimal)0.1`

Comment: well the OP declares a variable called `round` they should use the variable in your example that's being cast as decimal vs the 0.1 value.. but your answer is correct.. or `roundM` `+1` for the correct answer

Comment: @MarcGravell `0.1M` would be duplicate... Not really sure if it is still not a good idea to create many post for *exactly the same* error message so.